# I need to serialize an object to JSON. I'm using jQuery. Is there a "standard" way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I need to serialize an object to JSON. I'm using jQuery. Is there a "standard" way to do this?

My specific situation: I have an array defined as shown below:

```
var countries = new Array();
countries[0] = 'ga';
countries[1] = 'cd';
...
```

and I need to turn this into a string to pass to $.ajax() like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Concessions.aspx/GetConcessions",
    data: "{'countries':['ga','cd']}",
...
```

Comment: Does your API expect `application/json`? If not, use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: What are the bets the asker was expecting the answer to be something specific to jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use JSON.stringify(countries);

```
var c = {
   countries: countries
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Concessions.aspx/GetConcessions",
    data: JSON.stringify(c),
    contentType: "application/json"
...
```

Note that you will want to specify `contentType`; otherwise, URI-encoding is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to turn any object in to a JSON string:

```
var countries = new Array();
countries[0] = 'ga';
countries[1] = 'cd';
var json = JSON.stringify({ countries: countries}); // = '{"countries":["ga","cd"]}'

// or more simply:
var countries = [ 'ga', 'cd' ];
var json = JSON.stringify({ countries: countries}); // = '{"countries":["ga","cd"]}'
```

However, you should note that it's better practice to provide the `data` property of `$.ajax` with an object as jQuery will then create the JSON for you and at the same time escape any invalid characters and do any required encoding. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Concessions.aspx/GetConcessions",
    data: {
        'countries': countries
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution does not append the key name `{'countries':` to the result

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON.parse() to convert object to json

like this
countries = JSON.parse(countries);

object is convert in json and store in countries variable

Comment: thanx dear.. i get it